# Load Data from Excel Power Query to Access table

Tags: excel, powerquery, ms-access-2016

I have an excel file that collects data from multiple txt files into connected individual tables (1 table per each file) as connection only tables. I have done this because some of them contain >1m tables. In excel, I have appended those tables using Power Query/Apend function. I need to create a new table that contains all the data, however the resulting data is >1m rows, and I can't load it back to excel.

Is there a way to load my connection (summary of all tables) to access?

When I try to do that using import function in access, it does not recognise the connection as a table so I am not sure how to do this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load it to the Excel data model which doesn't have a 1m row limit.

You cannot load from PQ to Access (nor would you want to).